# Connect to Raspberry Pi via SSH

Tags: ssh

I find myself in a difficult problem. I want to `ssh` to my raspberry pi from linux. I did run the `ifconfig` command on the raspberry, I got `192.168.0.103`,
open the terminal in linux type in `ssh pi@192.168.0.103`, then it's prompting me for the password, I put it in and next line is just the cursor blinking, it's not doing anything and I have to kill the terminal session. Same thing happens if I try to ssh from putty, although I see the last log-on and after that I can't type anything.

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other steps that I need to take in order to connect?

Comment: Looks like it could be some lag.  If it's prompting you for the password it's probably the correct IP address.  Did you try keeping it there instead of killing the session?  In some cases, it could be that the IP address was entered wrong.

Comment: I changed the password on the raspberry, could log on but I couldn't type anything. Same thing on Putty on windows. Ping is working in both directions. I don't know what the issue might be. As for waiting, 5 minutes I think is more than enough.

Comment: As a work around for this issue, that I don't like that much would be to access it via the weaved application. You can follow the steps here:
[Weaved](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/internetaccess.md) Still, if somebody knows how to fix this issue, please help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have enabled the ssh feature on the raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

### UpdateMotd

One reason I love Debian and Raspbian is that I get basic, static banner/motd, then a command prompt immediately after I enter the correct password for ssh.

One reason I don't love Ubuntu Server is that it [runs a bunch of commands](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UpdateMotd) to generate a nice pretty, dynamic, informative banner/motd after I enter the correct password for ssh.
This causes a **significant** delay before I get a command prompt when I'm on a Pi.

Perhaps your Pi is running a bunch of commands to generate a banner/motd and is getting stuck?

**Edit**:  If this is the root cause, you should really look at the [official Debian motd page](https://wiki.debian.org/motd).

Comment: How can I check this? I haven't installed other than the OS and did update && upgrade.

Comment: The `libpam-modules` packages provides `libpam-motd` which superseded

Comment: (I keep forgetting to do shift-enter, and apparently I can't edit comments after 5 minutes...)  



I looked into more thoroughly, and `update-motd` was superseded by `libpam-motd`, which is in the `libpam-modules` package.  It would appear that `libpam-modules` is installed by default and provides other functionality, so you probably shouldn't uninstall it.
The official [Debian motd](https://wiki.debian.org/motd) page looks helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that Linux passwords show no cursor progress as a security feature? It may be showing the flashing cursor, and may be properly accepting input. Type your password and just hit enter. Hopefully that is it.

Comment: I tried with a wrong password and it's saying that the password is wrong.

Comment: *"Did you know that Linux passwords show no cursor progress as a security feature?"* First I've heard of that after almost 20 years as a user.  Do you have reference for this?  Unless you just mean the fact that entering a password doesn't echo, but in the question the OP (sort of implicitly) refers to this happening after hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once after having modified the file `~/.bashrc`. The rpi then tries to do the commands you put in this file and if you have done something wrong, it will go wrong after login...